# Perl : Json : Can I perform a GET within my POST processing?

Tags: json, perl, post, get, response

In theory... is it possible to 
parse a POST payload in which a url is supplied, 
then use the supplied url to perform a GET to acquire data,
that data is used to query a db and 
then send my response to the POST? 
Or will my original POST request pick up the GET response and kill everything?

I can't seem to find an example or reference to this being done anywhere... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and not just in theory.  I've done much the same thing myself.  Just use [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) (or your preferred HTTP client library) to perform the `GET` as usual.  Whether you're doing it within a `POST` handler or not makes no difference.